# Request path is changing with GET param?

Tags: node.js, express

I got very stranger problem with expressjs, req.originalUrl automatically changing!.

To take a param from client, I set code as bellows in server

create_new.js

```
router.get("/addItem", function(req, res, next) {

    objId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
    //1. check valid itemNumber
    res.render('addItem.ejs', {
        data: keyPair.public,
        title: "addItem",
        itemNumber: objId
    });
});

router.get("/addItem/:itemNumber", function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("from create_new :", req.params.itemNumber);
    var _id = req.params.itemNumber;
    var objId;
    //1. check valid itemNumber
    if (items.has(_id)) {
        objId = _id;
    } else {
        objId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
    }

    //console.log(items.has(_id));
    //console.log(req.originalUrl);
    //console.log(req.baseUrl);
    //console.log(req.path);

    res.render('addItem.ejs', {
        data: keyPair.public,
        title: "addItem",
        itemNumber: objId
    });
});
```

But in view is generated, instead of correct path for css and javascript libs, it automatically add a "createNewShop" as prefix of request.

It should to be look like that

```
GET /addItem/123/ 200 46.454 ms - -
GET /addItem/public/css/navbar.css 304 32.544 ms - -
GET /addItem/public/css/shop.css 304 65.018 ms - -
....
```

But actually it becomes

```
GET /createNewShop/addItem/123/ 200 39.646 ms - -
GET /createNewShop/addItem/public/css/navbar.css 304 31.533 ms - -
GET /createNewShop/addItem/public/css/shop.css 304 46.826 ms - -
....
```

My code in main app.js

```
app.use('/createnewshop',create_new);
```

Couls some one help me understand why and how to fix it
Thank a lot in advance

Comment: `app.use('/createnewshop',create_new);` of course causes all routes defined in `create_new` to start with `/createnewshop`. why would you expect otherwise?

Comment: No...I check with the first one (without param), it still build correct request for me @KevinB

Comment: I don't understand what that comment is saying.

Comment: I see. your css and js, are of course doing what you told them to do. You're likely using relative paths, which means it's goign to look for the assets relative to the current url, which is /createnewshop/something/etc

Comment: I mean, the first point one, I am using router.get("/addItem", function(){,,}) only, my view still make a correct request to server, with out any prefix...
So its why I confuse...

Comment: No, it went to `/addItem/public`, note the `/addItem`. The route will be based on the url of the page. Cmon now, this is html 101, not even node.js related in the slightest bit.

Comment: but in my view, I am using fix Url with
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css/imagePreview.css">

and in my app.js
I am using

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));;

Comment: That isn't a fixed url, it's relative. ../ goes up 1 folder from the **current** folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92428/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-hoanganh17b).

Answer (score 0):

Problem comes because of misunderstanding the different between absolute path and relative path on client request.
In client, if you using relative path with

```
("../somePath/someCssFiles)
```

Expressjs automatically add a sub folder before any request.
To fix it, instead of using relative path, try to use absolute path with

```
("/correctPath/correctSourceFile.css")
```

that will solves above problem